# Unable to run the URL without index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, drupal-7

Inside my **drupal** project www.example.com I have **codeigniter** project folder which is not running without **index.php** in the **url**.
Pls suggest any solution

Comment: please share your .htaccess

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /example/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Above htaccess is of codeigniter project www.example.com/example folder

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter URL rewriting will differ for servers. For linux you should use .htaccess file and for windows you should use web.config file. You can get those files by google it.